# How do I obscure my Wordpress install via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, redirection

(I am aware that security via obscurity is not recommended).

I am trying to hide the fact that I am using Wordpress. This [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) is helpful, but it only addresses the content (sort of). I am interested in having the following occur:

1. User tries to access any url with `wp*` as a substring via their browser.

   ***Result:*** Redirected to 404 page.
2. Blog user/administrator knows in order to login they should go to `http://example.com/blogin/`.

   ***Result:*** apache redirects them to `http://example.com/wp-admin/`.
3. If a user tries to directly access `wp-admin` from their browser they get sent to #1.

   ***Result:*** Redirected to 404 page.

***Things I've done so far***

1. I noticed for a default install of WordPress that I could access any of the `wp*` files in the (relative) root directory of the WP install. Specifically `wp-settings.php` was problematic because it gave away information about my set-up. If a user accessed it, it would spew some PHP errors and reveal part of the directory structure. I edited my php.ini file to turn `display_errors` off. Now accessing `http://example.com/wp-settngs.php` brings up a blank page.
2. This in itself isn't ideal because it reveals that `wp-settings.php` exists. In fact, accessing all the different `wp*` files is possible (with different results). I then put the following in my htaccess file:

   ```
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /
         RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} wp* [NC]
         RewriteRule .* - [F]
   ```

   This worked great! Anything with a `wp*` was routed to my custom 404 page. But now I can't access my admin page.
3. I tried to insert this line into the above code: `RewriteRule ^blogin wp-admin [NC,R,L]`. It was supposed to be right after `RewriteBase` but this didn't work.
4. I tried to do a:

   ```
   <Directory /home/example/wp*> 
    Order Allow, Deny 
    Allow from example.com 
    Deny from all 
   </Directory>
   ```

   hoping that a referer from my site (via the rewrite of the rule) would be able to access wp-admin, but not someone from outside. This didn't work either. apache complained that you can't use this directive from htaccess.

I've read the apache documentation; I understand the concepts, theoretically, but I need some practical help.

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that uses .htaccess instead of httpd.conf since my particular setup makes using httpd.conf inconsistent.

Comment: Have you tried renaming all wp* files to a different prefix as well as changing all the references to such files? I think this will be the easiest thing to do. Of course, you can go with URL rewriting, but then you will have to ensure that all links are not using wp* names as well, which is (in my opinion) pretty similar to the original suggestion.

Comment: I think one of the benefits of URL rewriting is that requested resources can be remapped to another prefix... I'm hoping that I can do this without renaming all the files (which is the point of going through this)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR; It is not possible to obscure WordPress by only using directives in your .htaccess file.**

Now cometh a tale of woe and horror. Our friend, fbh was right about the difficulty in hiding WordPress, it be not for yellow-bellied cowards. Arr! Here be the details of this (mis)adventure. Ye be warned!

### Motivation

I'm one of those guys that likes things perfect. I will <strike>spend</strike> waste time over-engineering something to be the 'right way'. One of things I didn't like about the default WordPress setup was that a user could type in http://ex.com/wp-settings.php and then all this php jargon would spew all over the place. I eventually was able to turn off errors via PHP but that led to a greater desire to only have things that made since be locatable resources from the server...and that everything else would be 404/3'ified to our custom search page. After that I got this idea that I'd like to completely hide the underlying framework (i.e. WP)... anyways... if you want to hide WP it's possible. But it's really hard.

### Steps to your doom

1. **Modify your PHP ini settings appropriately. *(i.e. turn display errors off)*** You might think this is unnecessary because if we're using .htaccess to reroute things, folks won't see errors because they can't access the error causing resources (I'm looking at you `wp-settings.php`). But errors could occur in displayed pages, so you definitely want them off. Just because `WP_*` directives are set doesn't necessarily mean that things will work the way you think they will. I found that on my server I had to set the display_errors to false FIRST, because WP_DISPLAY_ERRORS assumed that the default setting was false.

   Controlling PHP ini settings may be something as simple as putting a directive in your .htaccess file. Or, in my case, as complicated as creating a CGI handler and then putting a php.ini file there. YMMV depending on your set-up.
2. **Remove all access to files/directories with `wp-` prefix.** The idea is that your WP deployment is about your content, not about WP (unless it's specifically focused on WP). It doesn't make sense for people to want to see what http;//ex.com/wp-cron.php has... unless they're up to no-good. I accomplished this via this:

   ```
    # If the resource requested is a `wp-*` file or directory, poop to a 403. 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} wp-.*$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
   ```
3. **Learn how to just pass through mordor** By removing all access to `wp-*` you can no longer gain access to the administrative part of WP. That really sucks. In addition to that downer, you've just realized that you don't know what `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` really does. Well, what I tried to do is to give myself a 'secret' backdoor to the WP admin page. I used this code:

   ```
    # If the resource requested is 'mordor' (with or without an ending
    # slash) do a URL rewrite to `wp-login.php`. 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mordor/?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule mordor/?$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]
   ```

   So the URL: http://ex.com/mordor should bring us to the login page. The reason why we had the `REDIRECT` line in the step above is that since this URL gets rewritten to a `wp-*` URL, we don't want the first rewrite rule to get it. Since it's being redirected internally, `REDIRECT_STATUS` will be set correctly and it won't push us to 403/4 land.
4. **Remove wp-content** [Wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) has a great article on removing wp-content. You have to redefine some WP constants and that pretty much works. You also have to redirect all accesses from `wp-content` to 'whatever-content`. This probably won't be an issue if this is a clean deployment. If you're modifying a pre-existing deployment you'll have to do some extra stuff.
5. **Rewrite URLs to wp-content *optional*** `RewriteRule (.*)(wp-content)(.*) $1whatever-content$3 [NC,R,L]`. This goes in your .htaccess file. If your user tries to access some old content via a `wp-content` URL, it will get redirected here.
6. **Grep and replace all references to wp-content in your DB *optional***. You still have `wp-content` in your database. If you want to WP free you need to get rid of that stuff. I exported/mysql dumped my database, did a search and replace on the `wp-content` string to the new string. You might say... why do I have to do this if apache will rewrite my URLs? The problem is that the source code will contain these references so if you're really interested in obscuring WordPress, you need to do this. *Note: At this point I should've just stopped and accepted the reality that this wasn't going to work. But I wanted Mr. T to pity me.*
7. **Replace all references to `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` in the source.** A lot of the WordPress functionality depends on these two directories: `wp-includes` and `wp-admin`. This means these directory names are hardcoded in the source code. This means that you would have to create new directories (since PHP uses the underlying OS file system, not apache) to access these and then WRITES THESE OUT into the emitted html. This is just way too much trouble. I quickly gave up and went to the bathroom to take a poop.

### Lesson

Sure, I could've just read http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress and followed those steps. But I wanted the perfect site. Now I just want all those hours back. The biggest thing that prevented me from stopping was that I didn't read anywhere on the internet that this was a lot of work and almost impossible to do. Instead I read of people trying to do it with no sense of if they were successful or not. So, to my past self, whom I will send this to via Apple's Time Machine, please don't try and obscure WordPress. It's not worth it.

Comment: Well Avery, I'm also one the guy who wants to be perfect.. First I wanted to create a wordpress multisite by hiding the fact i'm using wordpress. I've gone through lots of problems and finally dropped the multisite idea. Because many plugins doesn't support multisite. Your 7th point indicates you replaced `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` text manually. I'm pretty sure you browsed each and every file and replaced manually. Thats because you missed some useful handy softwares. For instance you could have tried [grepwin](http://code.google.com/p/grepwin/downloads/list) which makes that job easier

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to hide that  you are using wordpress because of crackers, then you really got some work to do. If you do the wp* trick, what about wp-content and wp-includes?  Without being able to reach those, you will break the page and it will look horrible.

Also, there are so many things in Wordpress that this really takes some work - and you will most likely have to do a lot of it again when an upgrade is installed. (As a few redirects in Apache won't do the trick)

If you're just trying to hide it from Mr. and Mrs. everyone, then of course you should be able to somewhat do that with obscurity.

Have you read the "hardening Wordpress" guide?  If not, you should check it out: https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/ It gives a great introduction to a lot of things you can do.

Also, if you are this eager to hide the fact that you use Wordpress, why use it?

Comment: 1. **Re: wp-content/wp-includes** [See link in post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress) 2. I _have_ read the hardening WordPress guide. 3. Your last question can be easily answered by perusing the link I posted. I'm not trying to be rude, but this question has little to do with the technical merits of my own question. Lots of people use different tools but don't desire to advertise it. For some it's a business decision.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your configuration in the apache configuration. This can be an include of file like `/etc/wordpress/htaccess`.  This will allow you use `Directory` configuration directive.  However you will need to restart apache to load changes.  Use the graceful restart if you don't want service interruptions.

To restrict directory accesses with `.htaccess` files, they need to be in the appropriate directories.  They function much like the contents of a `Directory` configuration directive.  You may need to enable the required `.htaccess` options in your apache configuration.  This method is not as efficient as using command in the apache configuration as it needs to be reparsed frequently.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require editing my httpd.conf file because that can get over written (I'm on a virtual private host). I'll edit the question appropriately.

Comment: @Avry: You will need to place the directives you would put in the <Directory> configuration in a `.htaccess` file in the matching directory.  Note: Apache recommends you use the configuration if possible.  Use version control to guard against overwrites.